# SDL_CreateRenderer creates Invalid renderer

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a render in SDL2 by doing:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Window * w = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", 0, 0, 500, 500 0);
SDL_Renderer * r = SDL_CreateRenderer(w, -1, 0);
```

but after SDL_CreateRenderer I print SDL_GetError() and it shows:

> Invalid renderer

When rendering some things are rendered badly (this is part of a game). In this same computer on windows it works well and it does not show the "Invalid renderer" error.

I first downloaded SDL2 with apt-get install, but I later compiled it from source and I'm still having the same problem.

I'm not sure if it is important but I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome shell. I've got an ati video card and I'm using xserver-xorg driver. I was using fglrx but it had another problem with SDL so I changed it.

Any clues on what could be happening or how can this be fixed?

Comment: Try this: `SDL_Renderer * r = SDL_CreateRenderer(w, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);`

Comment: That didn't help either. The error still shows, but the issue of bad rendering apparently didn't had to do with this. It was because the image buffer wasn't cleaned before it was used. In windows it worked fine without cleaning the buffer.. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad rendering was because a buffer wasn't cleaned before being used. I thought it had to do with SDL_CreateRenderer because it showed an error in linux and not in ubuntu, but aparently it had nothing to do.